# How do I get the page title?

Tags: 8

How do I get the page title for use in a theme? I'm using **Drupal 8**.

I've tried searching the Drupal web site and I looked at a few questions on here and I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is what I'm trying in my template_preprocess_page:

```
  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $variables['page_title'] = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());
```

However, {{ page_title }} does not work. It seems as if the value is null.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate, because this is for the page template and in this template the title has moved to a block and you can put it in a region. If you want to access the title outside a region, it is still there:  `{{ page['#title'] }}`. So no need for the code mentioned in the duplicate.